# Can I install a new pressure-reducing valve inline with another one?

Tags: plumbing

I can't find my pressure reducing valve and am not sure if my house even has one. I checked for several feet around the water meter and for several feet before my main water lines enters my house. The rest of my main water line runs underneath my driveway. So I want to know, if putting one just after the water meter box would still be able to fix my water pressure problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could be a bit more forthcoming about what your water pressure problem is. Without knowing that, we can't tell what might address it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add additional PRV or regulators. The only possible side affect is a reduction in flow as they usually have restrictions. I have machines that I use 2 regulators one to do some basic isolation from the heavily fluctuating main air down to a fairly clean 90 psi then a second to provide a rock solid 80psi. And this machine runs great with no mishandling like that so Yes get the pressure down to what you want.

Comment: I apologize my water pressure is good when only one faucet is being used, but Im having a problem with low water pressure when multiple faucets are running at the same time or someone flushes a toilet while water is running.

Comment: All the homes we built the PRV was in the garage. I have not seen them outside I would think they would be prone to freezing outside. Have you looked inside ? Possibly close to the water heater supply that’s where most homes branch out. A PRV will reduce the pressure and in some cases extend your water heater, appliances that use water and faucet life. You may have a plugged PRV with low flow things work but 2 faucets or more and the pressure dives. 
Some look like blobs of metal with a screw. But any place on the incoming water line.